# Confusion regarding nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I have a question about Linked Lists. I spoke to a friend and am now confused.
Suppose that there are two variables of type struct node. One is ptr and the other is the header node.

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
};
struct node *ptr,*header;
```

What is the difference between

```
ptr=header
```

and

```
ptr->link=header
```

and

```
ptr->link=header->link
```

?
Edit:I mean semantically.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. What difference specifically do you mean? And semantically or syntactically?

Comment: @Downvoter I mean semantically.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre lol thanks.

Comment: If you want the program semantics, you need to show a program. Those 3 lines in isolation only have language semantics, specifically: the right-hand-side expression is assigned to the object yielded by the left-hand-side expression. I guess you weren't really asking what assignment means.

Comment: "Suppose that there are two variables of type struct node. ..." - None is of type `struct node`. They are `struct node *`. A pointer is not the same as the object it points to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming header is pointing to an allocated node initially, it will look like

```
                       +----------------+-----------+
                       |                |           |
header  +----------->  |   data         |  link+-----------> other node/NULL
                       |                |           |
                       +----------------+-----------+
```

After `ptr=header`, both `ptr` and `header` points to the same node

```
                       +----------------+-----------+
pointer +----------->  |                |           |
header  +----------->  |   data         |  link+-----------> other node/NULL
                       |                |           |
                       +----------------+-----------+
```

After `ptr->link=header`,

```
                       +----------------+-----------+
pointer +----------->  |                |           |
header  +----------->  |   data         |  link+----------+ 
                +--->  |                |           |     |
                |      +----------------+-----------+     |
                +-----------------------------------------+
```

after `ptr->link=header->link`, it would depend on where `header` and `ptr` are pointing

- if they point to the same node then this statement will have no effect.
- if they point to some different nodes then `link` pointer of both nodes pointed by `ptr` and `header` will point to the same node (or `NULL`).

  ```
                         +----------------+-----------+
                         |                |           |
  header  +----------->  |   data         |  link+--------------+                                                       |
                         |                |           |         |
                         +----------------+-----------+         +------> |
                                                                         |other node/NULL 
                                                                +------> |
                         +----------------+-----------+         |
                         |                |           |         |
  ptr     +----------->  |   data         |  link+--------------+ 
                         |                |           |
                         +----------------+-----------+
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you execute only one of these cases:

- `ptr=header` would make a pointer to the `header` node. This means the data of `ptr` would be the same as the data in `header`. `ptr->link` would also be the same as `header->link`
- `ptr->link=header` moves `ptr` infront of `header` in the list
- `ptr->link = header->link` makes `ptr` parallel to `header`, e.g.:

  ```
  ptr->data != header->data; // TRUE
  a = ptr->link;
  b = header->link;
  a->data == b->data // TRUE
  ```

where `a` and `b` are of type `struct node*`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand is to draw it out.[image]